# How do I use Loki's Small Object Allocator in Lua successfully?

Tags: memory-management, lua, c++-loki

I've read somewhere on here where someone recommended using Loki's Small Object Allocator for Lua to help improve allocation performance.  I read through the section in 'Modern C++ Design' and I think I've got a good enough understand on using Loki for this, with the exception of not using the `SmallObject` - Lua just wants raw memory, so I took a first stab at using the `SmallObjAllocator` directly.

The allocations seem like they are working, but everything completely fails once I tried to load a script (either using `lua_load()` with my own custom reader, or using `luaL_loadfile()` to read the file directly).

Here's my implementation of the `SmallObjAllocator` class:

```
class MySmallAllocator : public Loki::SmallObjAllocator
{
  public:
    MySmallAllocator( std::size_t pageSize, 
                      std::size_t maxObjectSize, 
                      std::size_t objectAlignSize ) : Loki::SmallObjAllocator( pageSize, maxObjectSize, objectAlignSize ) 
    { 
    }
    virtual ~MySmallAllocator() 
    { 
    }
};
static MySmallAllocator alloc_(4096,64,4);
```

And when I create the Lua state, I give it the allocation function that uses this new allocator:

```
masterState_ = lua_newstate(customAlloc_, &heap_);

void* customAlloc_( void* ud, void* ptr, size_t osize, size_t nsize )
{
  // If the new size is zero, we're destroying a block
  if (nsize == 0)
  {
    alloc_.Deallocate( ptr );
    ptr = NULL;
  }
  // If the original size is zero, then we're creating one
  else if (0 != nsize && 0 == osize)
  {
    ptr = alloc_.Allocate( nsize, false );
  }
  else
 {
   alloc_.Deallocate( ptr );
   ptr = alloc_.Allocate( nsize, false );
 }

 return ptr;
}
```

And here I go to load the file:

```
int result = luaL_loadfile( masterState_, "Global.lua" );
```

If i have a simple `for` loop in Global.lua the system never returns from the call to `luaL_loaloadfile()`:

```
for i=1,100 do
 local test = { }
end
```

What is wrong, how should I diagnose this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand the vote to close for "not a real question". Even before I edited it to add a question mark, it was still clearly a real question looking for help with a puzzling corner of the Lua API.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I should have written my question out better in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue that leaps out at me is that your custom allocator needs to behave like C's `realloc()` function. This is critical in the case where `osize != nsize` and both are non-zero. The key property of `realloc()` in this case is that it preserves the values of the first `min(osize,nsize)` bytes of the old block as the beginning of the new block.

You have:

```
    else
    {
            alloc_.Deallocate( ptr );
            ptr = alloc_.Allocate( nsize, false );
    }
```

which abandons all the content of the old allocation.

This is specified

> The allocator function must provide a
>   functionality similar to realloc, but
>   not exactly the same.

in the documentation for [lua_Alloc](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_Alloc).

Answer (score 0):

Good call! I really didn't understand what realloc() did, so you set me on the right track. I replaced the reallocation part to the code below and everything works now, but my performance right now is actually a bit worse than just using the HeapAlloc/HeapReAlloc/HeapFree I had before.

```
    void* replacementPtr = alloc_.Allocate( nsize, true );
    memcpy( replacementPtr, ptr, min(osize, nsize) );
    alloc_.Deallocate( ptr );
    ptr = replacementPtr;
```

I suspect an issue is because Loki uses malloc/free for each Chunk as well as when the size is > GetMaxObjectSize()...